# FreeBSD: How to install Django with mod_wsgi?

Tags: freebsd, python, apache-httpd, django

Using FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE.  I want to mess around with Django and I want a working setup on my freebsd system.  My understanding is I need to install python, apache, mod_wsgi, and django.  The [handbook section on Django](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-apache.html#AEN37483) talks about mod_python not mod_wsgi and I believe mod_wsgi is the recommended method.

I have the following installed on my system already from packages:

```
apache-2.2.17_1 
python26-2.6.6
```

What do I have to do get django working with apache?  Any tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got this working mostly with help from the following instructions: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnFreeBSD

Here's what I did (as root user):

**Reinstall apache**

I already had apache22 installed from a binary package but apparently the package version is compiled without thread support and you need threads for mod_wsgi.  So I did:
`pkg_delete apache-2.2.17_1`. This complained about php depending on apache, so I did: `pkg_delete php5-5.3.5`. Then I did `pkg_delete apache-2.2.17_1` again which worked.  Then I did `cd /usr/ports/www/apache22` then `make config` then I checked the check box `"[X] THREADS  Enable threads support in APR"` then `make` then `make install`.  Starting apache worked but I got an error "[warn] (2)No such file or directory: Failed to enable the 'httpready' Accept Filter".  I searched online and fixed it by doing `kldload accf_http` and `apachectl restart` then I added accf_http_load="YES" to my /boot/loader.conf so this change would persist after reboot.

**Install mod_wsgi**

```
cd /usr/ports/www/mod_wsgi3
make
make install
```

this automatically modified my httpd.conf file to add a loadmodule line

**Resinstall php**

(not strictly necessary but since I had to deinstall it above)

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/php5
make config (and set any options desired)
make
make install
```

**Test mod_wsgi install**

Following instructions at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide.
I created a file called test.wsgi with the following content in my document root:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

I added the following line to the end of my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/home/myusername/www/wsgitest/test.wsgi
```

(On my test box I have apache setup with a document root at /usr/home/myusername/www).  Then I did apachectl restart.  Then I went to http://localhost/myapp in my browser and voila! I saw "Hello World".

**Install pip**

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/py-pip
make
make install
```

Refreshed my shell so path would update.

**Install django**

```
pip install django
```

(this got me django version 1.3 yay!)
to confirm django install

```
python
import django
```

**Create django test app**

I created a new folder for my django test `mkdir /usr/home/myusername/www/djangotest`. Then

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

**Create django wsgi file**

created a new file /usr/home/myusername/www/djangotest/django.wsgi with the following content:

```
import os
import sys
path = '/usr/home/myusername/www/djangotest'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**Edit httpd.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /djangotest /usr/home/myusername/www/djangotest/django.wsgi
apachectl restart
```

visit http://locahost/djangotest in browser. It works!

**Edit httpd-vhosts.conf (optional)**

Now to get it working as part of virtual host.  Comment out the WSGIScriptAlias line in httpd.conf.   Then add something like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName mytest.whatever
 DocumentRoot /usr/home/myusername/www/djangotest
 WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/home/myusername/www/djangotest/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost> 

apachectl restart
```

After configuring hosts file, visit http://mytest.whatever in browser. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install anything special to mess with Django. The only things you need for a debug server that works are:

- Python
- Django itself
- Python modules for your DB if you want something other than SQLite

You have already got Python so I suggest:

```
easy_install pip
pip install django
```

Then follow the [Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/).
mod_wsgi comes into play when you [deploy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/) your application.

Comment: Thanks, in the end, I may go this route and I am familiar with the django development server. However I was looking to setup apache with mod_wsgi same as I use apache and php when testing my php sites.  I want my development to somewhat match deployed environment.